# AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'. Did you mean: '__setattr__'? How do I solve this?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I'm very new to kivymd and ran into a problem `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'. Did you mean: '__setattr__'?`

## main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (360,640)

class Main(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screenmanager = ScreenManager()
        screenmanager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("kv/key.kv"))
        screenmanager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("kv/home.kv"))
        screenmanager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("kv/menu.kv"))
        return screenmanager
    def keylogin(self, kode_key, nohp):
        pass
    def kodee(self):
        kode_key = self.root.ids.key_login.text
        nohp = self.root.ids.nomor_hp.text
        self.keylogin(kode_key, nohp)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().run()
```

## key.kv

```
MDScreen:
    name: "key"
    Screen:
        Image:
            source: 'images/gambar3.jpg'
            size_hint: None, None
            width: '360dp'
            height: '640dp'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.5}
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        Image:
            source: 'images/gambar1.png'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.5}
            size_hint: None, None
            width: '360dp'
            height: '180dp'
        MDLabel:
            text: "Selamat Datang!"
            font_size: '48dp'
            halign: 'center'
            pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.85}
            font_name: 'assets/font/font1.ttf'
            color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 255)
        MDLabel:
            text: "Masukan kode key untuk melanjutkan"
            font_size: '28dp'
            halign: 'center'
            pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.65}
            font_name: 'assets/font/font1.ttf'
            color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 255)
        MDFloatLayout:
            size_hint: .7, .07
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y': 0.44}
            TextInput:
                id: nomor_hp
                hint_text: "Nomor Ponsel"
                font_name: 'assets/font/ClassCoder.ttf'
                size_hint_y: .75
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5,'center_y': .5}
                halign: 'center'
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
                foreground_color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 255)
                cursor_color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 255)
                font_size: '18dp'
                cursor_width: '3dp'
                multiline: False
            MDFloatLayout:
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5,'center_y': .25}
                size_hint_y: .03
                md_bg_color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 255)
        MDFloatLayout:
            size_hint: .7, .07
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y': 0.34}
            TextInput:
                id: key_login
                hint_text: "Kode Key"
                font_name: 'assets/font/ClassCoder.ttf'
                size_hint_y: .75
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5,'center_y': .5}
                halign: 'center'
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
                foreground_color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 255)
                cursor_color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 255)
                font_size: '18dp'
                cursor_width: '3dp'
                multiline: False
            MDFloatLayout:
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5,'center_y': .25}
                size_hint_y: .03
                md_bg_color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 255)
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            text: "LOGIN"
            font_size: '18dp'
            size_hint: .5, .065
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.25}
            font_name: 'assets/font/font1.ttf'
            md_bg_color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 255)
            on_release: app.kodee()
        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: "GET KODE KEY"
            font_size: '18dp'
            size_hint: .5, .065
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.15}
            font_name: 'assets/font/font1.ttf'
            line_color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 255)
            text_color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 255)
            on_release:
                import webbrowser
                webbrowser.open('https://google.com')
        MDLabel:
            text: "Copyright"
            font_size: '18dp'
            halign: 'center'
            pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.08}
            font_name: 'assets/font/font4.Otf'
            color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 255)
        MDLabel:
            text: "Telegram"
            font_size: '18dp'
            halign: 'center'
            pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.05}
            font_name: 'assets/font/font4.Otf'
            color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 255)
```

I'm trying to retrieve text in `InputText` with `id:key_login` and `id:nomor_hp` but when I try to use `self.root.ids.key_login.text` I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 961, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'key_login'
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\projek py\Project\app\main.py", line 90, in <module>
     Main().run()
   File "C:\Users\Sumbulado\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 956, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\Sumbulado\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 574, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\Sumbulado\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 339, in mainloop
     self.idle()
   File "C:\Users\Sumbulado\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 383, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Users\Sumbulado\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 334, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Users\Sumbulado\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 302, in post_dispatch_input
     wid.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Sumbulado\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\button\button.py", line 1187, in on_touch_up
     return super().on_touch_up(touch)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\Sumbulado\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\behaviors\ripple_behavior.py", line 404, in on_touch_up
     return super().on_touch_up(touch)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\Sumbulado\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 179, in on_touch_up
     self.dispatch('on_release')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 727, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1307, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1191, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Sumbulado\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 55, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "D:\projek py\Project\app\kv\key.kv", line 78, in <module>
     on_release: app.kodee()
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "D:\projek py\Project\app\main.py", line 83, in kodee
     kode_key = self.root.ids.key_login.text
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'. Did you mean: '__setattr__'?
[Finished in 3.4s]
```

How can I retrieve the text in a `TextInput` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `kodee()` method:

```
def kodee(self):
    kode_key = self.root.ids.key_login.text
    nohp = self.root.ids.nomor_hp.text
    self.keylogin(kode_key, nohp)
```

your references to `ids` are the wrong `ids`. Those `ids` are defined in the the `"key"` `MDScreen`, so you can access them as:

```
def kodee(self):
    kode_key = self.root.get_screen('key').ids.key_login.text
    nohp = self.root.get_screen('key').ids.nomor_hp.text
    self.keylogin(kode_key, nohp)
```